# Joining two different output of custom transformer into one

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer, fme-flow-hosted

I am working on FME script which generated two output one is 1-1 where building outline are link to one parcel ( even if it related to multiple parcels) and another output is 1-M where building outline are link to many parcel which are relate to.

Below are data inspector output of two custom transformer. Which I need to joined as final output and exported to CSV file. FeatureMerge I tried not giving right output.

Output1:
[image]

Output 2:
[image]

Expected Output after joined:
[image]

FeatureMerger output: Highlighted column value is same all record which is not related to building outlines also.
[image]

FeatureMerger setting:
[image]

Comment: using a re-namer for output1_name and output2_name might also help see where the issue is merging.

Comment: output 1 has 1-1 relationship between outline_id and Name and output 2 has 1-m relationship between outline_id and Stacked_Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to this question. I used SpatialRelator because both input has same type spatial data I just wanted to join between them. SpatialRelator I just comparison as Equal operator because both data is similar only difference between attribute.

SpatialRelator -> ListExploder -> Output [image]

Answer (score 2):

I think we'd need to see the FeatureMerger parameters and which of the outputs is the Requestor and the Supplier. Without that, it's hard to diagnose a problem. Also, where does the 16441 come from (it's not in your "outputs" so it's hard to know if it's from output 1 or 2)?

But it looks like you need to have Output2 as the Requestor and Output1 as the Supplier. The Requestor/Supplier join attributes would both be outline_id. The Expected Output would come from the Merged port.

Don't check "Process Duplicate Suppliers" because I don't think there should be any. Accumulation Mode should be Merge Supplier and Conflict Resolution would be Use Requestor.

That way you should just get the Name column copied over.

If it's still going wrong, check for leading or trailing spaces causing join issues. An AttributeTrimmer is your friend there. Change the Comparison Mode from Automatic to Numeric as that might help. If it's coming from CSV then the default might be to treat it as a string.

Comment: consider 2332 instead of 16441. different view screenshot attached.

Comment: Name column from output 1 is only one value is repeating across all rows only.